# PDFPages package will not load in PDFLatex

Tags: latex, pdflatex, pdfpages, pdftex

I'm trying to include a PDF using `\usepackage{pdfpages}` but the package will not load. I'm getting the following error:

```
LaTeX Warning: You have requested release `2020-10-01' of LaTeX,
               but only release `2020-02-02' is available.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \nointerlineskip \AddToHook 
                                       {shipout/background}{\put (0,\ESO@yof...
l.188 }
       
?
```

Comment: Probably a mismatch between your latex kernel version and some package. Can you make sure your tex distribution is fully updated and (if this does not solve the problem) make a [mre] and show the .log file?

Comment: You're a legend, it's fixed.

Had to update :)

Comment: Glad to hear it is working! :)

Comment: I hate updates so much; now this will force me to lose two hours of my life waiting for entire damn latex distribution to upgrade ...